# How can i use sizeof(pointer). So i get sizeof(array). Pointer is pointing to array

Tags: c, pointers

See the comment section in the code. There I explained what I want to understand and what I know. 
[image]

How I can get 28 using ptr.
sizeof(arr) is giving me 28. (length of array elements) * sizeof(int)
But I can't figure out how to get this value using ptr.
I want this thing so I can get an array length using this method. In function own here.

```
int main (void)
{
    int arr[7] = {5, 8, 10, 50, 55, 98, 354};
    int result;

    /* ------- From here ---------*/

    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);   // sizeof(arr) = 28, sizeof(int) = 4. So size = 28/4 = 7

    result = anyFunction (arr);

    return 0;
}



int anyFunction (int array[]) 
{   
    int arraySize = sizeof(array) / sizeof(int);   // this line
}
```

`int *ptr = arr;` 
// Same as *ptr = &arr[0]

`size = sizeof(ptr);` 
// 8 is the size of pointer.

`size = sizeof(*ptr);` 
// size = 4.  4 is the size of arr[0]. Because its pointing to arr[0]. So its sizeof(arr[0]) or sizeof(5)

Comment: The compiler doesn't know exactly what a pointer might be pointing to at run-time. It might be pointing to the first element of an array. Or any arbitrary element inside the array. Or to just a single value. And if it points to the first element of an array, which array might it be? A program could use the same function to handle hundreds of different arrays, both created at compile-time, variable-length arrays created at run-time, or dynamically allocated "arrays" from `malloc`.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of error messages. Copy and paste the error message into your question body instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `sizeof(array)` when `array` is defined as `int array[]` I expect it to be the same as if it was defined as `int *array` since the size of the array isn't know.

The obvious solution is add a second parameter to `anyFunction()` with the array size.

Comment: In this case, `array` actually has type `int*` and not `int[]`. C changes a function parameter with array type to have pointer type instead. If you have an actual `int[]` type like `extern int A[];`, then `sizeof(A)` is an error, not the same as `sizeof(int*)`.